# Finding scaling behavior of functions with log factors

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For a function that shows power law behavior we can find the exponent from the slope of a log-log plot. But suppose there is a function of the form, $$ x^n log(x)^m,$$ how does one find $m$ and $n$ given the ability to evaluate it at various values of $x$.

Comment: Given the rather complex shape of the resulting dependences I doubt there is any general method beyond simple interpolation. By fitting your function with $n$ and $m$ as fitting parameters to the graphical data you have, you can obtain the estimates for $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Heuristically, we might notice that from $y=x^n(\log x)^m$ it follows that $\log y = n\log x + m\log(\log x)$. In logarithmic coordinates $\tilde{x}, \tilde{y}$, we have that $\tilde{y}=n\tilde{x} +m\log\tilde{x}$. If we can evaluate at $\tilde{x}=1$ we immediately recover $n$, otherwise we may let $\tilde{x}\to \infty$ to see a dominant linear behavior, from which we can compute $n$. Similarly, letting $\tilde{x}\to 0$ we see a dominant logarithmic behavior, and we can compute $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and that the model that you want to fit is
$$y=a\,x^n\,(\log(x))^m$$ as Ross Millikan already answered, you can make it linear taking the logarithms of both sides $$\log(y)=\log(a)+n\, \log(x)+m\, \log(\log(x))=b+n\, \log(x)+m\, \log(\log(x))$$ and a multilinear regression will easily provide *estimates* of the parameters.

However, you must take care that what you measure is $y$ (not $\log(y)$) that is to say that you look for the minimum of $$SSQ_1=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(a\,x_i^n\,(\log(x_i))^ m-y_i\right)^2$$ while the preliminary step corresponds to the minimization of 
 $$SSQ_2=\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\log(a)+ n\log(x_i)+m \log(\log(x_i)) -\log(y_i)\right)^2$$ which not the same and could even be quite different in the case of significant errors.

For illustration purposes, let us consider the following data set
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & y \\
 2 & 10 \\
 3 & 90 \\
 4 & 260 \\
 5 & 560 \\
 6 & 1000 \\
 7 & 1600 \\
 8 & 2380 \\
 9 & 3300 \\
 10 & 4400
\end{array}
\right)$$

The preliminary calculation would lead to $$\log(y)=2.97997+1.00476 \log (x)+3.68957 \log (\log (x))$$ corresponding to a good fit $(R^2=0.999981)$.

Using these as starting guesses, the nonlinear regression will lead to
$$y=15.183\, x^{1.26075} \,\log ^{3.31726}(x)$$ $(R^2=0.999994)$ and you can easily see how different are the parameters.

In the next table, I reproduce the values of the predicted $y$'s for each model
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & \text{linear} &\text{nonlinear} \\
 2 & 10 & 10.2178 & 10.7859 \\
 3 & 90 & 83.9988 & 82.8666 \\
 4 & 260 & 264.541 & 257.618 \\
 5 & 560 & 574.140 & 559.985 \\
 6 & 1000 & 1024.54 & 1006.02 \\
 7 & 1600 & 1621.96 & 1606.61 \\
 8 & 2380 & 2369.50 & 2369.41 \\
 9 & 3300 & 3268.40 & 3299.94 \\
 10 & 4400 & 4318.78 & 4402.23
\end{array}
\right)$$

I let you concluding about what is the best for interpolation or extrapolation.

Answer (score 1):

If $n,m$ are known to be integers it should be relatively easy.  The $\log x$ term varies very slowly so evaluate the function for a range of $x$ values.  Most of the variation will be due to the $x^n$ term so ignore the $\log$ term and pick the closest integer.  Then you can divide that out and find the $m$ term.

If you don't know they are integers you can just compute $\log f(x) = n \log x + m\log \log x +c$ for a bunch of points and use linear regression to find $n,m,c$